# Beginner HTML and Javascript: Changing input slider values to paragraphField.innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

College class assignment:

Below is the html code for my page. The assignment is to convert the slider range 1-10 so that when someone enters 1-4 there will be a text paragraph that makes a comment. When the user enters 6-10 there will be a different comment in the paragraph. Or better yet, a separate comment for each rating from 1 to 10.

Below is what I've come up with so far, but I'm not even sure if I'm on the right track. How do I get the values from the slider?

```js
var ratingSlider=document.getElementById("slider");
ratingSlider=addEventListener("blur", moveSlider);
 
function moveSlider() {
  var sliderField=document.getElementById("slider");
  var rating=sliderField.value;
  var theCritique="Yeah, man!";
  var paragraphField = document.getElementById("critique");
  paragraphField.innerHTML = theCritique;
}
```

```html
<div id-"rateUs">
  <label>Rate Our Restaurant</label>
  <p style="text-align:right;">Excellent</p>
  <input id="slider" type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" name=rateUs>
  <p style="text-align:left;">Poor</p>
  <p id="critique"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have restructure your above code, this below code will give exact output what you need.

```js
var ratingSlider=document.getElementById("slider");
ratingSlider.oninput = function() {
 var sliderValue =  this.value;
 var paragraphField = document.getElementById("critique");
 var theCritique = "";
  if(sliderValue >= 1 && sliderValue <= 2){
   theCritique="very Poor!";
   color = "red";
 } else if(sliderValue >= 3 &&  sliderValue <= 4){
    theCritique="Poor!";
   color = "#da5757";
 } else if(sliderValue >= 6 &&  sliderValue <= 8){
    theCritique="Good!";
   color = "#66bd66";
 } else if(sliderValue >= 9 &&  sliderValue <= 10){
    theCritique="Excellent!";
   color = "green";
 } else{
     theCritique="Okay!";
   color = "orange";
 }
  paragraphField.innerHTML = theCritique;
 paragraphField.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

```html
<div id="rateUs">
  <h1>Rate Our Restaurant</h1>
 
 <p style="float:right;text-align:right;">Excellent</p>
  <p style="float:left;text-align:left;">Very Poor</p>
 <div style="clear:both;margin:0 auto;width:50%;"><input id="slider" type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" name="rateUs"></div>
  <p id="critique" style="padding:10px;"></p>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vijayabal/Lr3s1qyo/1/

Comment: Thank you! That is really cool. I will study this and the other suggestions. This is my first attempt at using this site and you've all be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the `blur` event here because that fires when the element loses the focus, which isn't when you let go of the slider, it will be when another element gets the focus away from the slider. You want the `input` and/or `change` events (you may need both for a cross-browser solution).

You also need an `if/then` statement to determine what message to show and when.

You also had some syntax issues and unnecessary code. See the comments for details:

```js
// Get the references you need once
var ratingSlider = document.getElementById("slider");
var paragraphField = document.getElementById("critique");
  
// You had ratingSlider=addEventListener, but it should be:
ratingSlider.addEventListener("input", moveSlider);
 
function moveSlider() {
  var message = "";
  // The + right in front of ratingSlider explicitly converts the string
  // coming from the HTML value to a number so that a math comparison can be done
  if(+ratingSlider.value <= 4){
    message = "No way!";
  } else {
    message = "Yeah, man!";  
  }
  
  // Don't use .innerHTML when you aren't assigning any HTML, it's wastefull
  paragraphField.textContent = message;
}
```

```html
<!-- No need for an id on the div and don't give an element an id
   that is the same as the name of another, that just leads to confusion. -->
<div>
  <!-- <label> elements are for labeling form fields, not for titles.
       If you use a label, you either need to have it contain the element
       it is a label for, or use the "for" attribute that has the id of
       the element it is labeling. -->
  Rate Our Restaurant

  <input id="slider" type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" name="rateUs">
</div>
<p style="float:left;width:20%;margin-left:7em;">Poor</p>
<p style="float:left;width:20%;">Excellent</p>
<p id="critique"></p>
```

This should get you started, but if you are interested in a different comment for each value from 1 to 10, I'll give you a hint - an array can help you with that and you would be able to get rid of the entire `if/then` statement.

Comment: Thanks, Scott. Yes, I came across array and wondered if that might be what I need. I appreciate the hint, btw. I'd like to figure it out rather than have someone just give me the answer. This looks promising!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with this way, you can add more `else if` if you want to add more conditions.

```js
var ratingSlider=document.getElementById("slider");
ratingSlider=addEventListener("blur", moveSlider);
 
function moveSlider() {
  var sliderField=document.getElementById("slider");
  var rating=sliderField.value;
  
 var theCritique="";
  if(rating <= 4){
      theCritique="Yeah, man!";
  } else {
      theCritique="Another Text!";
  }

  var paragraphField = document.getElementById("critique");
  paragraphField.innerHTML = theCritique;
}
```

```html
<div id-"rateUs">
  <label>Rate Our Restaurant</label>
  <p style="text-align:right;">Excellent</p>
  <input id="slider" type="range" min="1" max="10" step="1" name=rateUs>
  <p style="text-align:left;">Poor</p>
  <p id="critique"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did use the suggestion for else if for rating 5.